# How can I get values from a map and have the displayed to the console?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I want to use a map to store a lot of information and grab it by using getline(cin, Number) to ask for user input.

```
std::map<int, int, int> Info;

Info[3321] = 3321, 180, 4;
Info[3260] = 3260, 300, 4;
Info[3053] = 3053, 250, 4;
```

I would like to get the information for from one at a time by typing in a number in the console. So if I type in 3321 in the console I want to get back 3321 180 and 4 into the console. I am not sure if a map is what I need to accomplish this but I am not certain what to use. Any information would be wonderful thanks.

Comment: Use `{}` to create those, switch to `std::map<int, std::tuple<int, int, int>>` or `std::array<int, 3>` as value type.

Comment: This helped a lot thank you very much for the quick answer.